# Looking for book on using 2D Fast Fourier Transforms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, book-recommendation, poissons-equation, fast-fourier-transform

I’m looking for a book on how to use 2D Fourier Transforms. One with **examples in code** or involving **finite data** is preferred, but I’ll take one that doesn’t so long as its a good book that uses 2D Fourier Transforms on PDEs.

Just for context, I have been trying to solve a 2D Partial Differential Equation (2D Poisson Equation) using a 2D Fourier Transform for about 6 months in both Python and Matlab. ***I created a finite, discrete dataset out of some periodic function and have been trying to obtain the solution using this***. I have tried posting my code to see if someone knows where I went wrong, but I have been unable to get an answer. It was my first time ever using an FFT at all and I have never taken a class on how to use them. I have consistently gotten close to obtaining the exact solution, but I appear to be missing something crucial. I have decided that the best way to find out what I’m missing would be by getting a book dedicated to it to find out exactly what I am doing wrong. I know this sounds silly, but I am at my wits end.

Comment: Perhaps a thing to consider is that an FFT does not perform a continuous time nor a discrete time Fourier Transform (the former of which you would be using for a PDE) but instead computes a different quantity called the Discrete Fourier Transform. To go from one to the other requires some assumptions on your original signal to do a sampling reconstruction otherwise you will always have aliasing problems.

Comment: I have ADHD so I am very poor w/ details and better w/ the bigger picture. Sorry! So, an FFT operation computes a DFT? And a DFT is NOT what I am supposed to be obtaining to solve a PDE? And I am instead supposed to find a continuous time Fourier Transform? Do I have that right?

Comment: Ah no worries - unless you are using a CAS all computerized FTs will be DFTs (that is to say both the space and frequency variable are discretized). PDEs are continuous and generally get solved with the usual ("continuous time") transform. Mathematically, going from Continuous Time Fourier Transform -> Discrete Time Fourier Transform (continuous in frequency but discrete in space) -> Discrete Fourier Transform (discrete variables in both) destroys information because of something called aliasing. To go backwards requires extra information about your PDE solution.

Comment: Most of these implications are discussed in signal processing textbooks when they talk about sampling. Oppenheim and Willsky is a good one to talk about the basic theory. Depending on what you need to be doing, there will be dozens of different schemes to retrieve or reconstruct a continuous function from a DFT.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I’m actually trying to solve a PDE that pertains to discrete, finite data. I just picked a random periodic function and tried to work back to the solution. The function was u(x,y) = 2^4 * x(1-x) * y(1-y). My plan after getting this to work was going to apply it to some dataset on a rectangular grid.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I apologize for not mentioning that earlier. I added this bit of context in bold and italicized. Does the DFT work for discrete, finite data? And does it still suffer from aliasing? I would assume so which results discrepancies between my obtained solution and the true solution.

Comment: All data will be finite and discrete when you feed it into an algorithm like it, but you are right that aliasing will always be a factor because of the process that leads to getting that discrete form from something continuous like a PDE kernel. One of the following two examples may stick with you: Even when going from continuous time to discrete time FT (i.e. keeping the frequency variable continuous) we lose FT transform properties. For example, the DTFT of a rectangle function is not a sinc $$\frac{\sin A}{B}$$ but rather looks like $$\frac{\sin A}{\sin B}$$

Comment: The other thing that might stick is [this visual explanation](https://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu//~ee120/fa16/handouts/dftho.pdf) of what happens in the frequency domain every time we take a step from continuous time -> discrete time -> discrete. Aliasing is what occurs when repeated pieces of the same signal overlap either in the time or frequency domains, which add up and destroy information since it is not an invertible process (it cuts off the highest frequency contributions, thus aliasing is not an injective process)

Comment: @NinadMunshi So I went ahead and got Signals and Systems Second Edition by Oppenheim and Willsky. Looks like something referred to as the "sampling frequency" is important here as it can be used with sampling theorem to obtain the correct signal, or solution in this case. Also, the wrong sampling frequency can cause aliasing. I'm using the Discrete Fourier Transform on spectral derivatives of the data so I'm assuming I need the spectral sampling frequency which I believe is Kappa instead of Omega. I believe I calculated Kappa for x and y correctly already.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I performed [This Process seen on the first page](https://atmos.washington.edu/~breth/classes/AM585/lect/FS_2DPoisson.pdf) prior to coming here searching for answers. k_n and l_p (it's supposed to be k_m and l_n; there are a few typos) I think are the spectral sampling frequencies for the Fourier Space that we've put our function into after performing the DFT. This is the fuller context of what I had been doing.